# What would cause a green color shift in the same photo between my Mac and my iPhone?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, color, iphone, macintosh

I just finished editing a picture and saved it in JPG on my Mac, which look perfectly fine. I sent it to my iPhone and the color completely shifted and look dull.

I was wondering what could make such a difference and why the color are changing between the two same pictures?

I made a screenshot on my phone to show you the difference. On the left is the phone, and on the right is my mac.

[image]

Comment: will it be possible for you to attach each photo individually with the meta data?

Comment: Also, what method did you use to send the image over to the iPhone

Comment: No I can't attach the two photos. Only the screenshot on iPhone allows me to see the difference of colours. I tried to send the photo back to my computer and the colours were fine. I used AirDrop to send the photo.

Comment: How are you viewing the image on the phone? How are you viewing the screen shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might have saved the JPEG with an AdobeRGB color profile, and the image viewer on the phone is ignoring this and assuming sRGB. You might want to check that, and save images as sRGB unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem on my mac when I would airdrop photos saved from photoshop to my iPhone. I was working in 16 bit in photoshop and all of the files I saved in 16 bit would do this same color shift. Try changing photoshop to 8 bit. As soon as I did this my airdropped files looked perfect.

-Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Just change all the pictures to CMYK and save them.

Open all of them back in Photoshop and convert them back to RGB and it should work.

Cheers!!

Comment: Can you explain why converting to CMYK and back to RGB may solve the OP problem ? It doesn't seems like a file format problem.